# jQuery not showing event namespace when using proxy

Tags: jquery, proxy, namespaces

In my script I want to have two types of click functionality, depend on what is clicked and I want to do it in a single function. I decided to make it with namespaces, but the console gives me undefined;

Here is the code:

```
$target1.on("click.Bst", $.proxy(self.selectNav, self));            

$target2.on("click.Bst.Type2", $.proxy(self.selectNav, self));
```

My function selectNav() executes on click, but when I try to get the event.namespace (event is passed as s function parameter) I get undefined.

```
selectNav: function(event){
 //other code runs  
 console.log(event.namespace);  //console log "undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`event.namespace` is only defined when the event was triggered via `.trigger` (e.g. `$target1.trigger('click.Bst')`), not through native DOM events. It has nothing to do with `.proxy`.

I have to admit that [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) could be clearer about this though.