# Event namespace is not showing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find my question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194329/jquery-not-showing-event-namespace-when-using-proxy).
When I use the event namespace, it doesn't show the namespace even without the proxy method.

HTML

```
<p>Get the click's namespace</p>
<button>Remove the click event</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").on("click.someNamespace",function(event){
    console.log(event.namespace);
  });
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").off("click.someNamespace");
  });
});
```

in more detail :http://codepen.io/ShawnHuang/pen/zaHui

There is another code is successful, but I don't know what's different between the two codes.
[click this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_namespace)

Thanks for reply!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

`event.handleObj.namespace`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZHp67/

<strike>Not sure it is publicly supported.</strike>

***Update:*** the relevant DOC can be find here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/#the-handleobj-object

Comment: Oh!!you got the namespace!!!
A little more question is what's different between my code and w3school example.
The fist one can get namespace with event.namespace, 
but the second one with event.handleObj.namespace.

Comment: When triggerring specific event (using namespace) the property namespace is set for the event object, otherwise not. The property handleObj of event seems to get in all case this property set as it is specific to the object which handle the event, not the event directly. This is how i understand it and as there is no DOC on this, i just speculate here

Comment: @Shawn: As I already said, in the w3school example they use `.trigger`: `$(this).trigger("custom.someNamespace");`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) and the example, I'd say that `event.namespace` is only defined if an event was triggered manually with `.trigger` and included a namespace:

> This will likely be used primarily by plugin authors who wish to handle tasks differently depending on the event namespace used.

```
$("p").trigger("test.something");
```

The "normal" mouse click is not bound to any specific namespace. You can also see in the w3schools example that they use `.trigger`.

Comment: I check the behavior of the code, it is successful.
Im only confused that I can't find the variable "namespace".
Maybe the jquery doesn't define at the click event?

Comment: As I said, `event.namespace` is only defined if the event was triggered programmatically with `.trigger`.

Comment: Makes sense that only if you are the one triggering the event then you can mark that event with the namespace. If you bind both `click.source1` and `click.source2` to an element, how is JQuery gonna know if a user click belongs to source1 or source2? That's the nature of an event-based architecture.